# Redirect domain (and all subdomains) to other domain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

What I would like to have redirected:

```
example.com          => example.net
whatever.example.com => whatever.example.net
```

Is this possible to do without setting up each individual subdomain as an alias in Apache and redirecting with mod_rewrite? Preferably, I'd like to do this with DNS only, but I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because I don't know Apache configs, but essentially all you have to do is setup a vhost for the example.com domain and a wildcard catchall for the subdomains, and then for that vhost redirect everyone to example.net or whatever.example.net using rewriting rules.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to set up DNS to point to the same web server for each of the domains.

Second, in your apache setup, there's more than one way.

1) If you're using VirtualHosts for each set of subdomains, you simply add a ServerAlias line, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.net
  [...] further commands
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHOst *:80>
  ServerName whatever.example.com 
  ServerAlias whatever.example.net
  [...] further commands
</VirtualHost>
```

2) If you prefer not to have to enter each host name, you can use [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html). Here's an example config:

```
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/vhosts/-2+
```

This means that every domain name will be connected to a path consisting of the domain name minus the last part. Example:

- `www.example.com` will use `/path/to/www.example`
- `www.example.net` will use `/path/to/www.example`
- `example.com` will use `/path/to/example`
- `example.net` will use `/path/to/example`
- `whatever.example.com` will use `/path/to/whatever.example`
- `whatever.example.net` will use `/path/to/whatever.example`

Comment: I was asking if it was possible without doing this.

Comment: In your post, you asked if it was possible without **mod_rewrite**. Be careful what you ask for :-) But I'll add some information about doing the same thing with mapping.

Comment: Sorry, just re-read the question and realised I didn't actually specify vhost. When I said "alias", I meant a vhost with serveraliases.

Comment: Does my second config, using mod_vhost_alias, give you what you need? If not, it'd probably help if you could clarify a bit further exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is mainly no as DNS is used only for making association between domain and its IP address (look the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896877/dns-redirect-domain-to-subdomain). So you should make changes in your `.htaccess` file according to this

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# handles http redirect sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.anotheriste.com/feed?v=$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles http redirect non sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.anotheriste.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles https redirect sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.anotheriste.com/feed?v=$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles https redirect non sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.anotheriste.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]
```

More comments to this you can find here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694503/htaccess-redirect-from-any-subdomain-to-another-domain-and-from-directory-to-que).